# FindOneBy не работет

Tags: php, symfony2

почему так

```
 $this->findOneBy(['cityId' => $id]);
```

в ответ

```
Unrecognized field: $cityId
```

однако в Entity

```
   /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="city_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $cityId;
```

Comment: Может быть, ` $this->findOneBy(['city_id' => $id]);`?

Comment: Неа. та же ошибка Unrecognized field: city_id

Comment: что в таблице? миграция срботала?

Comment: Все есть. Сработала давным-давно. Удалось решить проблему следующем образом, удалил $this->findOneBy(['city_id' => $id]); оставив репозиторий пустым вызвал магический Symfony метод this->findOneByCityId($id) он отработал нормасально, однако почему самописный не работает я

Answer (score 1):

Ключом в передаваемом массиве должно быть наименование столбца в таблице, но не имя переменной. 
Попробуйте так:

```
 $this->findOneBy(['city_id' => $id]);
```

Comment: Неа. та же ошибка Unrecognized field: city_id

Comment: А у Вас в самой базе, физически, этот столбец присутствует?
После генерации сущности Вы запускали команду 
app bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force?

Comment: Да и да
Удалось решить проблему следующем образом, удалил 
`$this->findOneBy(['city_id' => $id]);`

оставив репозиторий пустым вызвал магический Symfony метод

`this->findOneByCityId($id)`

он отработал нормасально, однако почему самописный не работает я понять не могу